# android dynamic TableRow with doInBackground not working?

Tags: android, tablelayout, tablerow, android-asynctask

```
//////  SeatLayout.java ///////////

public class SeatLayoutActivity  extends Activity
{
    private TableLayout mineField; // table layout to add mines to

    private Block blocks[][]; // blocks for mine field  
    private int blockDimension = 24; // width of each block
    private int blockPadding = 2; // padding between blocks

    private int numberOfRowsInMineField = 9;
    private int numberOfColumnsInMineField = 9;

    public ProgressDialog progressDialog; 

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


         progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(SeatLayoutActivity.this, "Getting data", "Loading...");
         new GetDataTask(SeatLayoutActivity.this).execute();  

          setContentView(R.layout.seatlayout);
    }


     private Boolean isOnline() {
            ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            NetworkInfo ni = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            if(ni != null && ni.isConnected())
                return true;

            return false;
        }

     private class GetDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Integer> {
         private Context ctx; 
         public GetDataTask(Context context) { 
             ctx = context; 
         } 

      @Override
      protected Integer doInBackground(Void... params) {

            if(isOnline()){



                mineField = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.MineField);      
                blocks = new Block[numberOfRowsInMineField + 2][numberOfColumnsInMineField + 2];


                //in feature below table(number of rows and columns) will based on RESET service response

                for (int row = 0; row < numberOfRowsInMineField + 2; row++)
                {
                    for (int column = 0; column < numberOfColumnsInMineField + 2; column++)
                    {   
                        blocks[row][column] = new Block(ctx);
                        blocks[row][column].setDefaults();                      

                    }
                }

                for (int row = 1; row < numberOfRowsInMineField + 1; row++)
                {
                    TableRow tableRow = new TableRow(ctx);  
                    tableRow.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams((blockDimension + 2 * blockPadding) * numberOfColumnsInMineField, blockDimension + 2 * blockPadding));

                    for (int column = 1; column < numberOfColumnsInMineField + 1; column++)
                    {
                        blocks[row][column].setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(  
                                blockDimension + 2 * blockPadding,  
                                blockDimension + 2 * blockPadding)); 
                        blocks[row][column].setPadding(blockPadding, blockPadding, blockPadding, blockPadding);
                        tableRow.addView(blocks[row][column]);
                    }
                    mineField.addView(tableRow,new TableLayout.LayoutParams(  
                            (blockDimension + 2 * blockPadding) * numberOfColumnsInMineField, blockDimension + 2 * blockPadding));  
                }


            }else{
                Toast.makeText(SeatLayoutActivity.this, "No connection..", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();           
            }

          return 1;
      }

      @Override
      protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {


        progressDialog.dismiss();
          super.onPostExecute(result);
      }
  }
}

///Block.java


package com.pxr.tutorial.xmltest;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.Button;

public class Block extends Button
{
    private boolean isCovered; // is block covered yet
    private boolean isMined; // does the block has a mine underneath
    private boolean isFlagged; // is block flagged as a potential mine
    private boolean isQuestionMarked; // is block question marked
    private boolean isClickable; // can block accept click events
    private int numberOfMinesInSurrounding; // number of mines in nearby blocks

    public Block(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
    }

    public Block(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public Block(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)
    {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    // set default properties for the block
    public void setDefaults()
    {
        isCovered = true;
        isMined = false;
        isFlagged = false;
        isQuestionMarked = false;
        isClickable = true;
        numberOfMinesInSurrounding = 0;

        this.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.square_blue);
        setBoldFont();
    }

    // mark the block as disabled/opened
    // update the number of nearby mines
    public void setNumberOfSurroundingMines(int number)
    {
        this.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.square_grey);

        updateNumber(number);
    }

    // set mine icon for block
    // set block as disabled/opened if false is passed
    public void setMineIcon(boolean enabled)
    {
        this.setText("M");

        if (!enabled)
        {
            this.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.square_grey);
            this.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        }
        else
        {
            this.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        }
    }

    // set mine as flagged
    // set block as disabled/opened if false is passed
    public void setFlagIcon(boolean enabled)
    {
        this.setText("F");

        if (!enabled)
        {
            this.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.square_grey);
            this.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        }
        else
        {
            this.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        }
    }

    // set mine as question mark
    // set block as disabled/opened if false is passed
    public void setQuestionMarkIcon(boolean enabled)
    {
        this.setText("?");

        if (!enabled)
        {
            this.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.square_grey);
            this.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        }
        else
        {
            this.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        }
    }

    // set block as disabled/opened if false is passed
    // else enable/close it
    public void setBlockAsDisabled(boolean enabled)
    {
        if (!enabled)
        {
            this.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.square_grey);
        }
        else
        {
            this.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.square_blue);
        }
    }

    // clear all icons/text
    public void clearAllIcons()
    {
        this.setText("");
    }

    // set font as bold
    private void setBoldFont()
    {
        this.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
    }

    // uncover this block
    public void OpenBlock()
    {
        // cannot uncover a mine which is not covered
        if (!isCovered)
            return;

        setBlockAsDisabled(false);
        isCovered = false;

        // check if it has mine
        if (hasMine())
        {
            setMineIcon(false);
        }
        // update with the nearby mine count
        else
        {
            setNumberOfSurroundingMines(numberOfMinesInSurrounding);
        }
    }

    // set text as nearby mine count
    public void updateNumber(int text)
    {
        if (text != 0)
        {
            this.setText(Integer.toString(text));

            // select different color for each number
            // we have already skipped 0 mine count
            switch (text)
            {
                case 1:
                    this.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    this.setTextColor(Color.rgb(0, 100, 0));
                    break;
                case 3:
                    this.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                    break;
                case 4:
                    this.setTextColor(Color.rgb(85, 26, 139));
                    break;
                case 5:
                    this.setTextColor(Color.rgb(139, 28, 98));
                    break;
                case 6:
                    this.setTextColor(Color.rgb(238, 173, 14));
                    break;
                case 7:
                    this.setTextColor(Color.rgb(47, 79, 79));
                    break;
                case 8:
                    this.setTextColor(Color.rgb(71, 71, 71));
                    break;
                case 9: 
                    this.setTextColor(Color.rgb(205, 205, 0));
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    // set block as a mine underneath
    public void plantMine()
    {
        isMined = true;
    }

    // mine was opened
    // change the block icon and color
    public void triggerMine()
    {
        setMineIcon(true);
        this.setTextColor(Color.RED);
    }

    // is block still covered
    public boolean isCovered()
    {
        return isCovered;
    }

    // does the block have any mine underneath
    public boolean hasMine()
    {
        return isMined;
    }

    // set number of nearby mines
    public void setNumberOfMinesInSurrounding(int number)
    {
        numberOfMinesInSurrounding = number;
    }

    // get number of nearby mines
    public int getNumberOfMinesInSorrounding()
    {
        return numberOfMinesInSurrounding;
    }

    // is block marked as flagged
    public boolean isFlagged()
    {
        return isFlagged;
    }

    // mark block as flagged
    public void setFlagged(boolean flagged)
    {
        isFlagged = flagged;
    }

    // is block marked as a question mark
    public boolean isQuestionMarked()
    {
        return isQuestionMarked;
    }

    // set question mark for the block
    public void setQuestionMarked(boolean questionMarked)
    {
        isQuestionMarked = questionMarked;
    }

    // can block receive click event
    public boolean isClickable()
    {
        return isClickable;
    }

    // disable block for receive click events
    public void setClickable(boolean clickable)
    {
        isClickable = clickable;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You mustn't modify and even access UI from non-UI thread. If you want to modify UI from `AsyncTask.doInBackground()` you should use `Activity.runOnUiThread()` or call `AsyncTask.publishProgress()` periodically and override `AsyncTask.onProgressUpdate()` method because it's executed on the main thread.

Comment: Thx..its working now.Now i am sending REST url response to  publishProgress(xml) and creating tablerow inside AsyncTask.onProgressUpdate(String... values).

Comment: Great! Now you can accept this answer if you think it's right.

Answer (score 0):

First thing is that this code will not compile.. because your trying to do UI related stuff in Background thread which has nothing to do with the UI.. adding view and showing `toast` should be done in `UI` `thread`, i mean in `postExecute()`

Answer (score 0):

write the table creation code in  onPostExecute()
`

`if(isOnline()){`

```
            mineField = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.MineField);      
            blocks = new Block[numberOfRowsInMineField + 2][numberOfColumnsInMineField + 2];


            //in feature below table(number of rows and columns) will based on RESET service response

            for (int row = 0; row < numberOfRowsInMineField + 2; row++)
            {
                for (int column = 0; column < numberOfColumnsInMineField + 2; column++)
                {   
                    blocks[row][column] = new Block(ctx);
                    blocks[row][column].setDefaults();                      

                }
            }

            for (int row = 1; row < numberOfRowsInMineField + 1; row++)
            {
                TableRow tableRow = new TableRow(ctx);  
                tableRow.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams((blockDimension + 2 * blockPadding) * numberOfColumnsInMineField, blockDimension + 2 * blockPadding));

                for (int column = 1; column < numberOfColumnsInMineField + 1; column++)
                {
                    blocks[row][column].setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(  
                            blockDimension + 2 * blockPadding,  
                            blockDimension + 2 * blockPadding)); 
                    blocks[row][column].setPadding(blockPadding, blockPadding, blockPadding, blockPadding);
                    tableRow.addView(blocks[row][column]);
                }
                mineField.addView(tableRow,new TableLayout.LayoutParams(  
                        (blockDimension + 2 * blockPadding) * numberOfColumnsInMineField, blockDimension + 2 * blockPadding));  
            }


        }else{
            Toast.makeText(SeatLayoutActivity.this, "No connection..", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();           
        }
```

`